# 403 error with LAMP and symfony

Tags: apache, symfony, ubuntu

With a LAMP server running on Ubuntu 16.04, I get the error in the log file defined as in conf :

```
[Tue Dec 26 16:56:35.930629 2017] [core:error] [pid 21749] (13)Permission denied: [client 127.0.0.1:43872] AH00035: access to / denied (filesystem path '/home/christophe/public_html') because search permissions are missing on a component of the path
```

I set my .conf file with the following :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName memory.test
    ServerAlias www.memory.test

    DocumentRoot /home/christophe/public_html/memory/web
    <Directory /home/christophe/public_html/memory/web>
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/memory_error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/memory_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

The access right are set for user `christophe:christophe` and www-data is part of the group christophe, the mod is 775 but even with the `www-data:www-data` I get the error.

The /etc/hosts file contains the line :

```
 127.0.0.1       memory.test
```

I seem to not have selinux installed as this solution is given in some other questions. I would not consider myself as a newbee and I succeeded to have many test environments working this way but this linux is a fresh installation and for a while no other website is working on it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you check that you have `0644` in the directory you are trying to serve?, besides, you also give permissions to `www-data` user to access that directory, note that the folder you are trying to serve is located in your home directory.

Comment: I have 775 but even with permission to www-data:www-data, it does not work.

Comment: "note that the folder you are trying to serve is located in your home directory" it permits to have it in a safe place in case of reinstallation. Is it forbidden ?

Comment: Not at all mate, what I want to say with that is that takes extra configurations, like permissions and users and groups, the best scenario for you would be using docker, but all depends on the features you have on your server.

Comment: I can do extra configuration. I already did that : "The access right are set for user christophe:christophe and www-data is part of the group christophe, the mod is 775 but even with the www-data:www-data I get the error. "

Comment: You are only adding `775` to the folder of the project?, if it is like that, it will not work, cause the permission system in unix is recursive, if you have a parent folder with different permissions than the child, this will prevent the permissions to work, best thing would be to make a symbolic link to the project folder inside a directory that www-data has access, like /var/www

Comment: I did it with -R option but I will take the var/www solution if nothing else can work

Comment: Yeah yeah, but I mean, you will have to make /home/christophe 775 as well, and that could take you to security issues as well, of course, in this cases you can make the symlink and that's it, but if you want to have it the way it is now, then you will have to put /home/christophe as 775 with www-data as owner user as well.